# How to perform a series of string replacements and be able to easily undo them?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, str-replace

I have a series of strings and their replacements separated by spaces:

```
a123 b312
c345 d453
```

I'd like to replace those strings in the left column with those in the right column, and undo the replacements later on. For the first part I could construct a sed command s/.../...;s/.../... but that doesn't consider reversing, and it requires me to significantly alter the input, which takes time. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Listed some example programs, could be anything free for win/lin.

Comment: Your question is still too vague for you to get high quality answers because you don't state enough information about what you are trying to do.    Are you trying to perform these replacements in another document, or are you trying to manipulate only the information shown here?   Replacements are not guaranteed to be reversible.   Think for example of what happens when two items in the second column are identical or where one item in the right-hand column already appears in the input before the replacements are made.   If you just need to swap these two columns, this is much much easier.

Comment: Do you have only one file? Can you create a copy of the file first, do your replacements, then just restore the file from the copy afterwards?

Comment: My input (in another document) is guaranteed to be reversible.

Comment: @Matt Ryall no, since the file undergoes further processing in between the two stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

unless (@ARGV == 3) {
    print "Usage: script.pl <reverse_changes?> <rfile> <input>\n";
    exit;
}
my $reverse_changes = shift;
my $rfile = shift;
open my $fh, "<", $rfile or die $!;
my %reps  = map split, <$fh>;

if ($reverse_changes) {
    %reps = reverse %reps;
}

my $rx = join "|", keys %reps;

while (<>) {
    s/\b($rx)\b/$reps{$1}/g;
    print;
}
```

The word boundary checks `\b` surrounding the replacements will prevent partial matches, e.g. replacing `a12345` with `b31245`. In the `$rx` you may wish to escape meta characters, if such can be present in your replacements.

**Usage:**

To perform the replacements:

```
script.pl 0 replace.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

To reverse changes:

```
script.pl 1 replace.txt output.txt > output2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Text editors provide "undo" functionality, but command-line utilities don't. You can write a script to do the replacement, then reverse the replacements file to do the same thing in reverse.

Here's a script that takes a series of replacements in 'replacements.txt' and runs them against the script's input:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open REPL, "<replacements.txt";
my @replacements;
while (<REPL>) {
    chomp;
    push @replacements, [ split ];
}
close REPL;

while (<>) {
    for my $r (@replacements) { s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/g }
    print;
}
```

If you save this file as 'repl.pl', and you save your file above as 'replacements.txt', you can use it like this:

```
perl repl.pl input.txt >output.txt
```

To convert your replacements file into a 'reverse-replacements.txt' file, you can use a simple awk command:

```
awk '{ print $2, $1 }' replacements.txt >reverse-replacements.txt
```

Then just modify the Perl script to use the reverse replacements file instead of the forward one.